# Accessing Tasmanian Sparse Grid from python using PyUblas, Boost.Python and py_tsg. Type mismatch in arguments for make_global_grid

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost

I'm using [py_tsg](http://rncarpio.github.io/py_tsg/) to call the sparse grid generator, Tasmanian (written in C++) from Python.  The py_tsg website indicates I need PyUblas and Boost.Python as prequisites.  I've got that all setup and am running the first example problem given to make sure everything is kosher (on the same py_tsg link given earlier).

So, everything seems fine except one thing... a type mismatch between one of the arguments in the Tasmanian grid method: make_global_grid.  Specifically, Python is passing a numpy.ndarray of ints to a pyublas::numpy_vector and the interpreter does not like it.

Here's the source:

```
import scipy, scipy.integrate, itertools
import pyublas
import _py_tsg as tsg

grid = tsg.TSG()
def fn1(x):     return scipy.exp(-x[0]*x[0])*scipy.cos(x[1])
dimension = 2
outputs = 0
level = 7
grid.make_global_grid( dimension, outputs, level, tsg.TypeDepth.type_level, tsg.TypeOneDRule.rule_clenshawcurtis, scipy.array([], dtype=int), 0.0, 0.0 )
points = grid.get_points()
weights = grid.get_weights()
sum = scipy.sum( [w*fn1(x) for (x,w) in zip(points, weights)] )
print("\nExample 1")
print("grid has: %d points" % grid.get_num_points())
print("integral is: %.17f" % sum)
print("error: %.17f" % scipy.fabs( sum - 2.513723354063905e+00 ))
```

And the stack trace:
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
TSG.make_global_grid(TSG, int, int, int, TypeDepth, TypeOneDRule, numpy.ndarray, float, float)
did not match C++ signature:
make_global_grid(TSG_Wrap {lvalue}, int, int, int, TasGrid::TypeDepth, TasGrid::TypeOneDRule, pyublas::numpy_vector, double, double)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Tasmanian provides a Python wrapper to their C++ library in versions 4.0 or later.  If you are running into a similar problem, check the Tasmanian documentation and use TSG 4.0 or later...